# Lodash/Javascript Compare array or objects, fail if any props match

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Preferably using Lodash, how can I compare two array of objects, and if any of the properties match, return false, while excluding 'name'.

```
array1 = [
  {
    "name": "componentA",
    "img": "www.url.com/image1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "componentB",
    "header": "this is the default header",
    "text": "here is a default text post",
    "buttons": [{
      "title": "a button",
      "url": "http://www.url.com"
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "componentB",
    "header": "this is the default header 2",
    "text": "here is a default text post 2 ",
    "buttons": [
      {
        "title": "a button 2",
        "url": "http://www.url2.com"
      },
      {
        "title": "a second button 2",
        "url": "http://www.url2_1.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

vs

```
array2 = [
  {
    "name": "componentA",
    "img": "www.url.com/imageA.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "componentB",
    "header": "header changed",
    "text": "text post changed",
    "buttons": [{
      "title": "button changed",
      "url": "http://www.website.com"
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "componentB",
    "header": "header 2 changed",
    "text": "here is a default text post 2 ",
    "buttons": [
      {
        "title": "button 2 changed",
        "url": "http://www.website2.com"
      },
      {
        "title": "button 2 changed again",
        "url": "http://www.website2_1.com"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

As you can see every property has changed except in `array2[2].text`, which would result in error.

The goal is to compare two arrays and be sure none of the default placeholder texts exists in the final array. if any default placeholder texts exists, do not allow a form to submit.  Each object has a `name` key that needs to be excluded from the check as it's what renders the component.

Started by using _.isEqual(), but unsure how go about checking each property between the two.

`let results = _.isEqual(array1, array2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.isEqualWith` and `customizer` function [`Loadash Ref`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith)

```js
let array1 = [{"name": "componentA","img": "www.url.com/image1.jpg"},{"name": "componentB","header": "this is the default header","text": "here is a default text post","buttons": [{"title": "a button","url": "http://www.url.com"}]},{"name": "componentB","header": "this is the default header 2","text": "here is a default text post 2 ","buttons": [{"title": "a button 2","url": "http://www.url2.com"},{"title": "a second button 2","url": "http://www.url2_1.com"}]}]
let array2 = [{"name": "componentA","img": "www.url.com/imageA.jpg"},{"name": "componentB","header": "header changed","text": "text post changed","buttons": [{"title": "button changed","url": "http://www.website.com"}]},{"name": "componentB","header": "header 2 changed","text": "here is a default text post 2 ","buttons": [{"title": "button 2 changed","url": "http://www.website2.com"},{"title": "button 2 changed again","url": "http://www.website2_1.com"}]},]
let array3 = [{"name": "component3","img": "www.url.com/image1.jpg"},{"name": "componentB","header": "this is the default header","text": "here is a default text post","buttons": [{"title": "a button","url": "http://www.url.com"}]},{"name": "componentB","header": "this is the default header 2","text": "here is a default text post 2 ","buttons": [{"title": "a button 2","url": "http://www.url2.com"},{"title": "a second button 2","url": "http://www.url2_1.com"}]}]


function check(val1,val2,index){
 if(index === 'name') return true
}

console.log(_.isEqualWith(array1,array2,check))
console.log(_.isEqualWith(array1,array3,check))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is working well so far... but lets say I have a constant object, in each array, with the name 'componentZ'.  How can I ignore that one while checking everything else?

Comment: @jobiin you can adjust `customizer` function as per your need, and return value accordingly from it, i.e. since you want to ignore object with some value, you test for such values in coustomizer, similarly as we are doing for name here